# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5400 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) { errno: -111, code: 'ECONNREFUSED'

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, express, rest

I am creating an Express server with a REST API and a PostgreSQL database inside a Docker container, and everything works fine when I run the server on my machine. The server connects to the database through an exposed port without any issues. However, when I try to put my project inside a Docker container using a Dockerfile, as soon as I create a container with the image of my project, it indicates that it cannot establish a connection with the database, even though the container is in the same Docker network. The error message is as follows:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.22.0.2:5400
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '172.22.0.2',
  port: 5400
}
```

After encountering this error, I tried to find a solution on Stack Overflow and forums. I found that I had to change the configuration for the connection to my database, specifically the host property, and I had to put the IP or container name where my database was hosted. That's exactly what I did.

config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    user: "postgres",
    host: "tododataBase", // or IP 172.22.0.2
    database: "todoapp",
    password: "123",
    port: 5400,
}
```

connection.js:

```
const connection = new Client(config)
```

I made the configuration change, but when I ran it, I got a different error, which is as follows:

```
Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN tododataBase
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26) {
  errno: -3001,
  code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'tododataBase'
}
```

After this, I tried to do the same thing but with Docker Compose, but I was getting the same errors. What can I do? Please, I've been stuck on this for a day :(

I forgot to share my Docker Compose, so here it is. However, this Docker Compose is modified because I tried to change everything, such as the ports, the database name, and more. Nevertheless, in the end, it gave me the same error as before.

```
version: '1'

services:
   backend: 
    build: .
    image: server-todoapp:1.5
    ports: 
     - 4500:4500
    environment: 
        SEQ_DB: todoappdb
        SEQ_USER: dbuser
        SEQ_PW: root123
        PORT: 4242
        DATABASE_URL: postgres://dbuser:root123@db:5300/todoappdb
    volumes:
       - ./:/src

   db:
     image: postgres
     ports:
     - "5300:5432"
     environment:
       POSTGRES_USER: dbuser
       POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root123
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbYNI.png)

Comment: can you please share compose.yml for further analysis

Comment: Yes, I updated my question with the complete image of my Docker Compose and a general overview of how my project is structured, which is really basic. Thank you for taking the time to look into it :)

Comment: I think 'Error: getaddrinfo' is DNS problem, your machine cannot resolve the real address to the DB with this name. As stated in one answer you can add the name in hosts -file. BUT, my guess is that after resolving this, you will go back to 'ECONNREFUSED' which basically says that your connection was blocked/refused -> either you are using wrong port or you haven't allowed the port in DB end / firewall / etc.

Comment: The hostname you use should be the compose service name of the database, i.e. `db`. Not `tododataBase`.

Comment: PostgreSQL's normal port is 5432, and you need to use that normal port number when connecting between containers.

Comment: Thanks friend, I just changed the port from 5300 to 5432, which is the default, and it worked, although I don't understand why it wasn't working. I was supposed to have exposed the Postgres container on port 5300. Could you give me an explanation to study or any indication of why this method is used? Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

i have faced this issue, when i was working with phpmyadmin and want to connect with the docker container of mysql so i have used the ipaddress of that machine.
you sghuold use ip address 172.22.0.2 at the place of host:tododataBase
secondly, you should also resolve the hostname by /etc/hosts file so it can resolve the host because your system not know that hostname and also your docker cotainer host not know that name. they know ip addresses.

Comment: To resolve the hostname, do I need to make changes when the container is running or stopped? Because when it's stopped, I can't access it to make any changes using Docker Desktop. However, when it's running, I can access it, but I still get an error:                                                                             code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -98,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 4500
}                                                                              
I'm going to try it one more time, and I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Docker provides a DNS system for communication between containers; you never need to manually look up a container IP address and you never need to edit `/etc/hosts`.